# No sound via HDMI on a 4k TV on Fedora

Tags: fedora, audio, hdmi, multimedia

I've had issues with Debian on my USFF HP ProDesk 400 G5 and the connected 4k TV (Screen tearing, resolution and sound issues), so I wanted to give Fedora a chance.

I've booted the latest Workstation Live image (Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-35-1.2) but the HDMI output is not available as a sound output device in the gnome settings.

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost-live 5.14.10-300.fc35.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 7 20:48:44 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20632 Analog [CX20632 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

No sound is produced for `speaker-test -D hw:0,3 -c 2 -l 1` (or `hw:0,7`). `hw:0,0` is the built-in speaker and works.

The output of `speaker-test`:

```
speaker-test 1.2.5.1

Playback device is hw:0,3
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 64 to 1048576
Period size range from 32 to 524288
Using max buffer size 1048576
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 262144
was set buffer_size = 1048576
 0 - Unknown
 1 - Unknown
Time per period = 10.936630
```

Previously, on Debian I had set the resolution to 1080p, then the HDMI-2 device allowed audio output, but had crackling noise on high pitch sounds. On fedora, the audio output device isn't available, independent of the set resolution.

**edit:** I also just noticed this following lines multiple times in the `dmesg` output:

```
[ 2557.558262] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: HDMI: pin NID 0x5 not registered
[ 2557.568877] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: HDMI: pin NID 0x6 not registered
```

How can I make the HDMI output device usable on Fedora?

Comment: Hi, Emma, please try Fedora 35 RC 1.4 - it's gonna get released in just a few days: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Test_Results:Fedora_36_RC_1.4_Desktop -> Workstation live  x86-64 image

Comment: Hi @ArtemS.Tashkinov thanks for the note, I'm writing a new flash drive at the moment, I'll report back with the results.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'm super surprised, but with the live `Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-36-1.4.iso` it works out of the box! HDMI-2 is recognized as an audio output device. 4k, with sound no crackling. Any idea what might cause this on Fedora 35?

Comment: An old kernel, old PipeWire or old WirePlumber. Any of the three could cause your issue.

Comment: Fascinating! Thank you @ArtemS.Tashkinov. I reckon I'll wait for the release of Fedora 36, then switch my systems from Debian/Ubuntu to Fedora!